# Loop over liked documents in mongodb aggregation

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

i have collection with a couple of documents which has a field with a ref to the next document. for e.g.

#### schema

```
const books = new mongoose.Schema({
  _id: { type: String, index: true, required: true, default: () => nanoid() }
  title: { type: String },
  nextBook: { type: String, ref: 'books' } 
  (..)
})
```

#### documents

```
const books = [
 { 
   _id: '1',
   title: 'book type A Edition 1',
   nextBook: '2'
 },
 { 
   _id: '2',
   title: 'book type A Edition 2',
   nextBook: '3'
 },
 { 
   _id: '3',
   title: 'book type A Edition 3',
 },
]
```

now i have, within an aggregation, for e.g. the document with _id: 1 and want to loop over the documents, refenced by the nextBook field until the nextBook is undefined (it is the last book) and return the document as "lastBook"

how can i achieve this "loop" ?

kind regards

Comment: Can you add, what is the expected output

Comment: @CharchitKapoor the expected output should be the document with _id: 3 -> 
{ 
   _id: '3',
   title: 'book type A Edition 3',
 },

Comment: So for each book, you need to find the lastBook, that's it right?

Comment: @CharchitKapoor exactly

Answer (score 0):

You will have to use aggregation pipeline, with `$graphLookup`, to recursively fetch all the linked books, and then pick the last one for each book. Like this:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $graphLookup: {
      from: "collection",
      startWith: "$nextBook",
      connectFromField: "nextBook",
      connectToField: "_id",
      as: "nextBooks"
    }
  },
  {
    "$unwind": "$nextBooks"
  },
  {
    "$sort": {
      "nextBooks._id": 1
    }
  },
  {
    "$group": {
      "_id": "$_id",
      "nextBooks": {
        "$push": "$nextBooks"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$addFields": {
      "lastBook": {
        "$cond": {
          "if": {
            "$eq": [
              {
                "$size": "$nextBooks"
              },
              0
            ]
          },
          "then": null,
          "else": {
            "$last": "$nextBooks"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$project": {
      lastBook: 1
    }
  }
])
```

Here's the playground [link](https://mongoplayground.net/p/Z93J_4zErbR).